# Loop through different variations of a word

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, brace-expansion

I would like to loop through different variations of a word, but can't think of how the syntax would be arranged, for example:

```
for host in server(01,02,03,04)db
    do echo $host
done
```

would return:

```
server01db
server02db
server03db
server04db
```

How would I structure that loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curly braces instead of parenthesis:

```
for host in server{01,02,03,04}db 
do
  echo "$host"
done
```

Look at `man bash` for `Brace Expansion`

Comment: Those are commonly known as "braces" or "curly braces"

Answer (score 0):

Another:

```
$ for host in server{01..04}db 
  do
    echo "$host"
  done
```